# How to get property from content page in umbraco where editor type is textbox

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I want to get the details about a field on umbraco contentpage where property type is textbox and alias or id is not known

Comment: Why is alias not known?

Comment: This is a for a package which returns the types of fields on a content page, so we do not know the alias or id of the user content page

Comment: What details about each field do you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the property without knowing the alias or id, then you will need to iterate though the properties and you may get more than one of that type. I'm not sure what the context is for this, but it appears that the Umbraco published cache does not include the property editor type.  This means you can't do something like the following in a view:

```
foreach (var property in Model.Properties.Where(x => x.PropertyType.PropertyEditorAlias == "Umbraco.Textbox"))
{
    var propValue = property.Value;
}
```

But you can use the ContentService to get this data:

```
var docProperties = ApplicationContext.Services.ContentService.GetById(Model.Id).Properties.Where(x => x.PropertyType.PropertyEditorAlias == "Umbraco.Textbox");
foreach (var property in docProperties)
{
    var propValue = property.Value;

}
```

Warning, this will query the database as it is not using the Umbraco Cache.

Comment: docproperties always returns a null despite there being multiple fields of said type

Comment: I tested the code and it worked for me. Perhaps you could run it in debugger and make sure you are getting the right node data? Does it (ApplicationContext.Services.ContentService.GetById(Model.Id).Properties) contain any properties?

Comment: Node data is correct, all other data is present but properties count is always zero somehow